# Autoindent in vim always change 8 or more leading whitespace into tabs. How to fix that?

Tags: vim

It is demonstrated below:

```
while (head == tail)
{
....if (head == 100)
....{
........blahblahblah  <hit_return>
<-tab-->"SEE? Autoindent change the leading whitespace into tab"
```

Can I fix this and let autoindent always use whitespace as indent character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the expandtab option. To insert space characters whenever the tab key is pressed or when vim automatically indents a line, set the `expandtab` option:

```
:set expandtab
```

To change all tab characters into the appropriate amount of spaces (controlled by the `tabstop` option and `8` by default) after `expandtab` is set, do:

```
:retab
```